# Custom Plugin Not Showing Up In The List (works fine while debugging - not when deployed through deploy.bat)

Tags: plugins, deployment, nopcommerce

I am currently having an issue with my plugin not being displayed in the plugin list within admin.

When I run this straight from VS2010 is works perfectly. I have checked and the description file appears to be OK and the plugin is present in the plugins folder once deployed (using the deploy.bat).

I have noticed there is a massive list of DLLs being deployed with the plugin but don't think that is the issue (although it would be nice to tidy that up to - all references are set to do not copy)

Are there any other things I could be missing? I am fairly new to development and have checked al the things that seem to be obvious to me.

I have already read and checked the following:

http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/13404/plugin-not-showhing-up-in-plugin-list.aspx
http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/14259/plugin-not-copied-to-deploy.aspx

Any assistance will be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being the publishing to different IIS site without realising so it was updating the DLL in the wrong folder...

Answer (score 1):

Have you properly documented yor plugin code?

```
<?php<br>
/*<br>
Plugin Name: Name Of The Plugin<br>
Plugin URI: h ttp://URI_Of_Page_Describing_Plugin_and_Updates<br>
Description: A brief description of the Plugin.<br>
Version: The Plugin's Version Number, e.g.: 1.0<br>
Author: Name Of The Plugin Author<br>
Author URI: h ttp://URI_Of_The_Plugin_Author<br>
License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL2<br>
*/<br>
?><br>
```

(from wpcodex)

Comment: COnfused as to why you have PHP tags in a .NET plugin?